# Bounty reward amounts

Tags: support, bounty

I was about to offer a bounty on a question and noticed that the 50 point bounty is not available anymore.

I think before I was offered the option between 50, 100, and 150. Now it is 100 - 500 in various increments.

Is this because I have a bounty out already, or was there a site wide change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two factors will increase the minumum bounty.

- If you answered the question, you start at 100 for a bounty.
- If you offer multiple bounties on one post, it increases exact iteration.

Comment: nice, that was the other difference that I didn't pay attention to.